# FBX with Weight or Deformation support?

Tags: modeling, game-engine, edit-mode

I am trying to edit models for a game. Specifically hair. In 3ds MAX, there is a special window that allows you to export the file with deformations, considering in this game, hair has physics:

[image]

I like 3ds max for modeling, however, I like blender for texture mapping. It seems when I edit the model in Blender after I edit it in 3ds MAX, in game, it is stiff as in it isn't flowing or having any flow to it at all. Even though 3ds max has this feature, it makes the hair very glitchy in the game. Is there a way for blender to export FBX files, with the support for deformation, for the hair to have physics in game? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The only animated mesh deformations Blender can export to FBX are:

- Armature-driven ones.
- Relative shape keys.

So if you can bake your physics into shapekeys, or use a 'fake-physics' armature, it should work.

PS: don’t know Max, but I would bet their “deformations” are similar to Blender’s “shape keys”?